# Set selected index in a listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, selectedindex

I have a listview on a Win Forms where I need to programmatically set the selected index. Apparently, ListView does not have a SelectedIndex property that can be set. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: There is an event - SelectedIndexChanged that you can configure to do what you need.

Comment: `listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;`

Comment: @TaW you should post that as the answer with a little explanation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Apparently, ListView does not have a SelectedIndex property that can be set.*

Indeed and it is logical as you can have **multiple** Items selected.

Hence it does have the `SelectedItems` and also the `SelectedIndices` property; both are read-only.

To **select** an Item simply set its `Selected` property to `true`:

```
listView1.Items[someItemIndex].Selected = true;
```

If the ListView' s `MultiSelect` property is false, this will deselect all other Items. If it is true the Item is added to the set of selected Items..

To **de-select** all Items in one go, use `listView1.SelectedIndices.Clear();` or `listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();`..

Comment: It seems you post the comment and me the answer concurrently. +1 to your answer :)

Comment: To select only one item, it seems it's enough to set `MultiSelect` property of the `ListView` to false and just select the new item.

Comment: Yes. But maybe multiselect is still required and only the selection shall be reset. I tried to cover all aspects.. Calling `Clear` once is clearer than clearing and re-setting MulitSelect, imo.

Comment: I didn't thought of testing the `MultiSelect` property to `false` when I wrote the code, and the code seems useless now.

Answer (score 3):

You can select or deselect an item by setting the [`Selected`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.selected(v=vs.110).aspx) property, for example: `this.listView1.Items[2].Selected = true;`

**Edit**

To select only one item, it's enough to set `MultiSelect` property of the `ListView` to `false` and just select the new item.